# How do I read different csv and write them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to read certain csv files which don't have a certain name it is alreadry in a folder which I define in the directory  glob.glob, select two columns which I specify and print these csv one by one

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd;   
import numpy as np;       
import glob;   
import os;  
all_files = glob.glob("C:/Users/Gamer/Documents/Colbun/Saturn/*.csv");   
file_list = [];   
for f in all_files:;   
    df = pd.read_csv(f,header=0,usecols=["t","f"]);
df.to_csv(file_list);
```

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: Sorry , now i put my code.

Comment: This is my first time posting

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: in the final part, df.to_csv(file_list). The output is 1 csv file and i reed 3 csv files and i want 3 csv files converted

Comment: Reed 3(or more) csv and print 3 csv (or more)

Comment: `df.to_csv` needs to be  **in** the loop, and *it* needs a unique file path each iteration.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your example.

Comment: Please fix the formating. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: I fixed, so you say that i have to put df.to_csv(file_list) in the cicle for?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reed 3(or more) csv and print 3 csv (or more)

This will save to a file not print.

```
file_list = []
for i,f in enumerate(all_files):   
    df = pd.read_csv(f,header=0,usecols=["t","f"])
    df.to_csv(f'filename{n}.csv')
    file_list.append(f'filename{i}.csv')    #??
```

Comment: it says that n is not defined.
my csv files have randoms names

Comment: My bad, see edit.  You need to provide a filename for each iteration. Your question was vague in that respect.

Comment: Thx, that solved my problem. Now i need to fix the name .

Comment: if i want to add a column of percentages should i always add it to the loop so that it works on all csv?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages. [Pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect use of df.to_csv, the function takes in path object (implementing os.PathLike[str]). I would suggest appending the df in file_list inside the loop. Refer: [df.to_csv function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) on how to use the save csv function.